# Is it possible to build a Process Builder with Campaign Members?

Tags: process-builder

Process builder isn't displaying Campaign Members as an option for an Object to kick off a process. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes you can write process builder on Campaign Members

Comment: Any idea why it isn't showing up in the list of objects for me?

Comment: Is marketing user checked on your user?

Comment: Yes, Marketing User is selected. I can see Campaigns but not Campaign Members.

Comment: Does your user have access for Campaign Member? B/c it also is working for me.
I am sysadmin, are you also sysadmin?

Comment: if you have access to Campaign then you will always have access to Campaign members. That's the inbuilt functionality of SFDC

Comment: I have access as a System Admin. Seems strange that I would access to Campaigns but not Campaign Members on process builder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the admin profile permission to access the campaign member object.

**Preface:**

I believe there are two different UIs for adjusting permissions and I'm only familiar with the newer UI. If you're using the older one you might have issues accomplishing this. [Info on the enhanced profile layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_profiles_using_enhanced_ui.htm&type=0)

There is some confusion about how campaign member security is handled as I believe at one point this was completely inherited from the campaign object; however, this is not true currently.

**Updating Permissions:**

Select your profile, in this case I'm doing the sys admin profile:

[image: profile]

Click on object settings:

[image: Object Settings]

Locate Campaign Member:

[image: Campaign Member]

Verify permissions are as expected.

Other than that you need to make sure marketing user is selected for your user to gain access to the objects and you should verify sharing settings for campaigns/campaign members as well.

[Org Wide Defaults](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sharing.htm&type=0)

[Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&language=en&type=0)

Comment: I enabled enhanced profile views and was able to locate Campaign Members and verified it looks like yours. (--) However I cannot edit the permissions specifically for campaign members. I can only control field level security on the object.